# The PNG image I created using GDAL's createcopy method looks 48-bit on Windows

Tags: gdal, png

I use GDAL `ceatecopy()` method to convert a 16bit TIF file to a PNG file. Why the PNG file generated is 48bit? But I can successfully display it on ArcGIS. Thumbnails on Windows are black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 16-bit TIFF has one channel of data with 16 bits. A PNG file is (typically) three channels of data usually representing red, green, and blue levels. So your 48-bit PNG looks like it has three 16 bit channels, one for each of the colour levels, giving 3x16 = 48 bits. Most PNGs only have 8-bit colour channels, but it seems GDAL is preserving the 16 bits of data from your TIFF as 16 bit channels in the PNG, which seems reasonable given reduction to 8-bit colour channels would mean losing information.